# Lead Conversion Issues with validation rules

Tags: visual-workflow, validation-rule, lead-conversion

I have validation rule on Account Shipping Address.

```
AND (
ShippingCountry = "United States" || ShippingCountry = "Canada",
isBlank(ShippingState)
)
```

The standard Lead Mapping feature of Salesforce Maps the lead Address to the Account Billing Address.

When Converting Lead to Account, the validation rule fires. As a result, the lead conversion throws an error 'Shipping State Required'

I don't want to disable the Lead Setting 'Require Validation for Converted Leads' because that would mean all validation rules will be skipped.

After researching, One idea I came across [here](https://sfdceinstien.wordpress.com/2019/03/30/bypass-validation-rule-for-lead-conversion/) was Bypassing the Shipping Address Validation error by creating two Custom checkboxes. One on lead, one on Account.
However this requires me to now create a flow to undo the check box. Which is fine, however, this errors out the flow that exists on the Account, which basically Autopopulate the Account Name based on the Account Address.State.

Does anyone have other suggestions or ideas to bypass the validation rule for lead conversion to Account ?

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

- Create a checkbox formula field on Lead called `Is_Lead__c`. Default value = `true`
- Create a checkbox field on Account `Is_Created_by_Lead_Conversion__c`.
- Add to your lead conversion mapping rules `Lead.Is_Lead__c => Account.Is_Created_by_Lead_Conversion__c`

Then, change the VR to:

```
  IF (ISNEW() && Is_Created_By_Lead_Conversion, /* ignore shippingState check on new lead conversion */
      FALSE,  
      AND(    
       ShippingCountry = "United States" || ShippingCountry = "Canada",
       ISBLANK(ShippingState)
      )
   )
```

Plus, you get the bonus of knowing which Accounts were created by lead conversion. The same technique can be used for Opportunity VRs.

Comment: Thanks @Cropredy. That's the best solution.  However, now a flow on the Account object throws error when converting the lead 'flow tried to update records: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION: Please select Shipping State'. Seems like I have to think of all other automation.

Comment: the flow is probably running after update so ISNEW() is no longer true

Comment: You are right, Flow is running After Update.  I came across a solution 'Bypass Validation Rules in Flows' . Not sure if this is the correct approach as this would mean, I would have to do this for all the validation rules now and in future, that would affect Lead Conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Would not this be a better solution?

1. Make one of the standard Lead Source picklist field values the default. For example, set the “Other” value as the default.
2. Since this field is already mapped to the Account Source field by default, an Account created through Lead Conversion will have the Account Source field value set to “Other.”
3. We then need to update the Validation Rule so that it is triggered only when the Account Source field is blank. This will prevent the Validation Rule from being fired during Lead Conversion, and it will still apply to Accounts that are being created.

   AND (ISBLANK(TEXT(AccountSource)),
   ShippingCountry = "United States" || ShippingCountry = "Canada",
   isBlank(ShippingState)
   )

**Advantages of this approach.**

**Saves fields:** We do not need to create the two custom fields: one on Lead and one on Account.

**Less configuration:** Saves you from configuring the mapping between the two fields, reducing your metadata for deployment.

**Easier deployment:** You won’t need to deploy the two fields and the updated field mapping, which may result in faster and easier deployment.

**Scalable:** This solution is also scalable. For example, since the Lead Source field is also mapped to Contact: Lead Source and Opportunity: Lead Source fields, you can easily update the Validation Rule on the respective objects to bypass it.